# Books similar to The Lord of the Rings: dark elves, different gods, Thommas, red-haired woman

Tags: story-identification

This morning I was riding in the train when I heard two fellows discussing an upcoming movie. They likened it to The Lord of the Rings with orcs and elves and (I think) magicians etc. They also mentioned that it is a story that originally appears in books. I've been trying to figure out what books these are, because I am interested in potentially reading them.

Below are all the details I can recall:

- There are elves, similar to the elves in The Lord of the Rings, but these are dark elves. (They mentioned they can reuse the elves from lord of the rings when making the movie and just color the hair black)
- Also, there was something of red elves that may or may not be included in the story
- Pretty sure there is magic related to the story in one form or another
- There was something about different gods (e.g. god of chaos, god of x, god of y, etc.) which may or may not still exist
- They mentioned the name Thommas a few times in a way that makes me think he is one of the main characters
- They mentioned something about some bloke (may or may not be the Thommas fellow mentioned above) being stuck somewhere eternally fighting something, or his body being stuck there or some similar plot
- They mentioned orcs, but I'm not sure whether or not this is included in the story or part of the discussion about Lord of the Rings

Like I said, I heard this from 2 blokes in the train, and I was not about to walk up to them and ask what story they are discussing. I hope I've gathered enough details for someone to help me identify the story.

---

Oh, I just recalled one last thing. There was something about a queen or some other important woman who is apparently a red head.

Comment: Was the character they talked about being imprisoned called Macros ( the black) by any chance? If so, rand al'thor's answer is correct, the series is Feist's Magician.

Comment: Princess Anita in Silverthorn (Second book in the first trilogy) is a redhead:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverthorn_%28novel%29

Comment: Boluc Papuccuoglu - I see your red-headed Princess in the second book and raise you a red-headed Queen in the first - Queen Aglaranna.

Comment: @DavidS, true! Totally forgot that Aglaranna was a redhead too.

Comment: When they mentioned "Thommas", did they pronounce it with two M's?

Comment: @DavidConrad: These blokes were English speaking of a different nationality (Indian, I think), so it's hard to say whether or not they pronounced Thommas with on or two M's.

Comment: Some of this reminds me of Pratchett's [Tiffany Aching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_Aching) books. (Elves are creatures to be afraid of in the Discworld series.) Even though other items do not fit the list, I use this as an opportunity to advertise these wonderful books here. `:)`

Comment: Did they mention another main character named Pug?

Comment: @randal'thor: They did mention a few other characters, but I simply can't remember the names. I think I recall Thommas because I was on a train at the time: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Tank_Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Tank_Engine)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like [Raymond Feist's *Magician*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel)) (and other books by him set in the same world). There are "dark elves" (aka moredhel) and many different gods. One of the two main characters, named Tomas, gets stuck with an ancient being inside his body which he's eternally fighting.

I haven't heard anything about this book being made into a film though, so it could be something completely different.

Comment: Queen Aglaranna is a red-headed Elf Queen in this book, seems a likely candidate.

Comment: I haven't heard anything about a film either, but Betrayal at Krondor is a computer game in the same universe...

Comment: I don't know whether or not this is what was being discussed in the train, but this and the other books in Riftwar saga really looks like something that I am interested in reading. I don't much care about movies and whatnot. Finding something that I would want to read in a way was the original intention of the question, so thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps the movie [Seventh Son](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1121096/)? The lead/protagonist is named Thomas. And magic abounds in the form of various types of witches. No elves as specifically named, but some of the characters/outfits do look kinda like them, mostly dark haired. Some of the monsters may be considered orc-like.

Based on the first book in the [Last Apprentice series](https://thespooksbooks.fandom.com/wiki/Wardstone_Wiki), also known as The Wardstone Chronicles written by Joseph Delaney.

**"Oh, I just recalled one last thing. There was something about a queen or some other important woman who is apparently a red head."**
The big bad of the movie and the first book is a malevolent witch named Mother Malkin who happens to be portrayed by the redheaded Julianne Moore.

[image: malkin]

Basic Summary:

> Young Thomas is apprenticed to the local Spook to learn to fight evil spirits. His first great challenge comes when the powerful Mother Malkin escapes her confinement while the Spook is away.

There are a group of ["Old Gods"](https://thespooksbooks.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Gods), (Golgoth, The Fiend, Ordeen, The Bane, Aphrodite, Artemis/Hecate, Hephaestus, The Morrigan, Pan (The Horned God), Siscoi, Zeus)

> The Old Gods were beings who controlled different elements and aspects of life in the ancient world.  However, they were slowly forgotten until almost none remembered them.  However, many of them are still remembered in the minds of witches and necromancers. Also the Old Gods seem to be remembered by old stories and myths from long ago. The greek gods are also counted as the Old Gods as well. Some believe that the Old Gods are good, but in reality they are pety and cruel and plague mankind.

Comment: this has my vote as its actually a movie.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the [World of Warcraft](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0803096/) movie.

the "Red elves" - Blood elves from the game.

thommas?? - maybe the [Thomas](https://wowwiki-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Thomson) from the franchise too.

There is magic and Elves and Orcs in Warcraft movie.

Comment: This was my best guess as well. There are Old Gods, Orcs, Red Elves, High Elves, many forms of magic and there are characters imprisoned for 1000+ years.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - Illidan was imprisoned for 10.000 years.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero
The World of Warcraft movie, will be purly orcs and humans, and maybe the highelves/dwarves. there will be no taurens, nightelves, old gods, ect. but the high elves will not be in red and will have blonde hair, they dont become the blood elves until after this movie by about 50 years or so.